# Duvida referente a dispose() em JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Estou tentando fazer uma verificação na tela de login, para saber se já existe o arquivo de configuração onde são definidas as informações de acesso. Caso não exista, era suposto dar `dispose` na tela de login e abrir a de configuração.

Por algum motivo, o `dispose` não funciona quando coloco o método na inicialização, dessa forma:

```
public class ViewLogin extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public String login;
public String nomeDoUser;
public String usern;

public ViewLogin() {
    initComponents();
    verifyConfig(); <--
    setIcon();
    colorOverlay.setBackground(new Color(51, 51, 51, 155));
    passField.requestFocus();
    this.nomeDoUser = nomeDoUser;
    this.usern = usern;
}

public void verifyConfig() {
    File f = new File("config.ini");
    if (!f.exists()) {
        new ViewConfig().setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    }
}
```

Porém, se eu colocar em um botão, funciona perfeitamente:

```
private void btnLoginMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    File f = new File("config.ini");
    if (!f.exists()) {
        new ViewConfig().setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    } else {
        UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();
        if (dao.checkLogin(usrField.getText(), passField.getText())) {
            new ViewHome(dao.nomeDoUser, dao.usern).setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        } else {
            new ViewLoginError().setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

O que posso estar fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você mal construiu a tela da classe `ViewLogin` e já está querendo fechá-la, pela chamada do método `verifyConfig()`, que mesmo sendo outro método, ainda faz parte da construção da tela dentro do construtor da classe. O fato de funcionar no listener do botão é porque todo o processo de renderização da tela está completo neste ponto.

Note que a tela somente será exibida após o construtor ser finalizado, pois a Thread do swing faz muitas outras operações de registros de ouvintes até a tela ser declarada visível.

Forçar esse tipo de comportamento eu não vejo com bons olhos, ainda mais porque se uma tela depende de uma verificação para ser usada ou não, isso deveria ser verificado fora dela e não no seu construtor.

Para mostrar na prática como seu código está rodando, veja o exemplo abaixo, onde adicionei alguns `printlns` em diferentes fases da construção da classe, incluindo um `dispose()` no construtor:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class FrameBlank extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            System.out.println("creating frame...");
            FrameBlank frame = new FrameBlank();
            System.out.println("setting visibility...");
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public FrameBlank() {
        initComponents();
        System.out.println("disposing...");
        this.dispose();
    }

    public void initComponents() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 300));
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        pack();
    }
}
```

O resultado ao abrir a tela é sempre o abaixo:

> creating frame...
>   disposing...
>   setting visibility...

Perceba que a visibilidade nem foi configurada e o `dispose()` já foi chamado, mas até esse instante, a tela o ignorou pois ainda estava em construção, e deu andamento normal ao restante do código.

Comment: Foi o que imaginei @diegofm... Inicialmente a verificação era antes da tela de login abrir, porém por algum motivo, o design que criei, fica totalmente diferente, como por exemplo as labels que quando não somem, elas ficam com fontes totalmente diferentes.

Comment: @WilianSilva o ideal é verificar isso antes de dar `new` na classe, assim vc reduz até o uso de recursos de forma desnecessária quando não for pra abrir a tela.